# Automatic weight painting does not deform the mesh of my character?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I found a situation that I don't understand. It seems that the automatic weight painting does not work with the girl that I have rigged using rigify. I don't understand the reasons of this behaviour,because :

1) I'm trying to deform the parts of the mesh that are attached with the DEF bones

2) I'm repeating the steps that I did previously with the boy and it worked

3) I split the mesh into several pieces and I have attached each piece to the rig called "rig.girl" under the armature modifier tab

Let's take as example the bone called "DEF-forearm.L.001". I would like that it deforms the "braccio_sx_girl" aka arm_left_girl. What I do to achieve this output ?

a) I select the bone "DEF_forearm.L.001" ;

b) I press SHIFT and then I select "braccio_sx_girl" ;

c) I change from object mode to weight paint mode ;

d) I do weights / assign automatic from bones ;

but the mesh is not deformed....

NB : I repeated again the steps from "a" to "d" with the boy and it worked.

This is the [blender file](http://www87.zippyshare.com/v/bJ3hEakY/file.html).
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, you have "Face selection masking for painting" enabled. Disable it by clicking on the icon in the red circle on the image attached, and everything will back to normal.[image]

Comment: I'm trying to fix this problem since 2 days. You come back and boom. You fixed it. You are the man. How did I not notice it ? I don't know.